# Interpretation if integrate a bivariate distribution with respect to one component only

Tags: probability, bivariate-distributions

while solving an integral problem for bivariate distribution, I encounter with some problem when interpreting the results.

Let say that I have a bivariate continuous function $f(t,x)$ where $t$ and $x$ represents time $T$ and biomarker value $X$ respectively. If I solve the following integral (1),

$$(1)   \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(u,x) du = f_X(x)$$

I will arrive to the definition of the marginal distribution of $f_X(x)$. However, if I solve the following integral (2),

$$(2)    \int_{t}^{\infty} f(u,x) du = ??,$$

Do I get probability $P( T>t \cap X=x )$ or $S(t | X=x)$? Here, $S(.)$ is the survival function.

This is because I have read some literature regarding right-censoring and encounter with situation where solving (2) will produce $S(t|X=x)$. But if we recalled the conditional probability, the conditional survival should be as following,

$$ S(t | X=x) = \frac{\int_{t}^{\infty} f(u,x) du}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(u,x) du}$$
$$ S(t | X=x) = \frac{\int_{t}^{\infty} f(u,x) du}{f_X(x)}.$$

Did I missed out anything? Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: I find the notation $$S(t | X=x) = \frac{P(T>t \cap X=x)}{P(X=x)}$$ problematic because $P(X=x)$ is zero. It might be better to *define* the conditional survival function as $$S(t | X=x) = \frac{\int_t^\infty f(u,x)\,du}{f_X(x)}\,.$$ You want $S(-\infty|X=x)$ to be one, not $f_X(x)\,.$

Comment: Great. I just edited the question. For your last comment, do you mean solving (2) only results to S(t|x) only if S(−∞|X=x) equal to one?

Comment: I interpret your nomenclature as follows: $T$ is a time until something survives. Typically $T$ takes values in $[0,+\infty]$ but why not $[-\infty,+\infty]\,.$ The unconditional survival probability until $t$ is then $P(T>t)\,.$ What you call survival function $S(t|X=x)$ is the survival probability conditional on $X\,.$ It should behave like a probability: take values in $[0,1]$ and be one when $t$ is the lowest possible value that $T$ can take. *Disclaimer.* I don't know the background of this. You have barely given a context and no rigorous definitions.

Comment: You're correct, the background is revolving survival analysis. Now it makes sense to me why it is common in survival analysis that solving (2) results to $S(t|X=x)$. It is because usually $X$ represents covariate (such as group, gender etc.). Since the focus of survival analysis mostly comparing probability to survive between group, thus we're only concern with distribution of $T$. No wonder you mention $S(-\infty|X=x)$ not necessarily $f_X(x)$. Thanks @KurtG.